# Determine an orthonormal basis for the subspace $W$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal, projection-matrices

The subspace $W$ in $\mathbb{R}^5$ is given as the solution space to the linear system of equations (you can see it in the picture).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OKwc.png)

Determine an orthonormal basis for $W$ and write the vector $x =[1,1,1,0,1]$ as a sum of two vectors, one in $W$ and the other in $W^⊥$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It's better to write out the question here, than to link to a picture offsite.